# Setting the Decimal Separator in Latex invoice package

Tags: latex, invoice

The figure shows as 12500.00 - I want it to show as 12,500.00. Any ideas? I also want the £ sign to show before in total column as £12,500.00

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{invoice}


\renewcommand{\$}{\pounds}



\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{ Banana}


\opening{\underline Sent }

\begin{invoice}{Sterling}{0}
\caption{Baby Limited}
  \ProjectTitle{77 }%
  \Fee{Full Quarter; 25 June - 29 September 2022} { 625} {20}



\end{invoice}


\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre], including a documentclass and all packages necessary to compile your code.

Comment: Please don't edit in additional questions. Stackoverflow works best if each problem has its own post.

Answer (score 0):

The invoice package internally used the `siunitx` package. This means you can specify a group separator like this:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{invoice}


\renewcommand{\$}{\pounds}

\sisetup{group-separator = {,}}




\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{ Banana}


\opening{\underline Sent }

\begin{invoice}{Sterling}{0}
\caption{Baby Limited}
  \ProjectTitle{77 }%
  \Fee{Full Quarter; 25 June - 29 September 2022} { 625} {20}



\end{invoice}


\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 8.2 of the [user manua](https://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/invoice/invoice.pdf)l suggests using `comma` as a package option:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[german,comma]{invoice}
```

That worked for me.